# How to use 2 url in 1 function ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have 2 table, warehouse and item category, i wanna show my table in select option ajax. I managed to display select option item category.

My Ajax Code

```
$(function () {
  var i = 0;
  $("#add-more-item").click(function () {
    ++i;
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/admin-master/get_item_category",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(res){
          let option = "";
          $.each(res,function(itemcategory_name,id_item_category){
             option += '<option value='+id_item_category+'>'+ itemcategory_name+ '</option>'
          });
            $(".add-more").append(
              '<tr><td><select class="form-control" id="warehouse"></select</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="item_code['+i+']" class="form-control" placeholder="Kode Barang" required></td>
               <td><select class="form-control" name="itemcategory_id['+i+']"><option>-- Pilih Ketegori --</option>'+option+'</select></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="item_name['+i+']" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Barang" required</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="item_weight[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : 200 kg" required></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="item_height[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : 200 cm" required></td>
               <td><input type="number" name="item_qty[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Contoh : 200 " required></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Keterangan Barang"></td>
               <td align="center"><button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-md"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td></tr>'
                );
            }
        });
        
      });
```

how do i retrieve the data warehouse ? should i create 2 urls to fetch category and warehouse items? can i make 2 urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you not combine warehouse and item category to 1 url ajax

Example `/admin-master/get_item_category_and_warehouse`

and in controller

```
return response([
  'item_categories' => $itemCategory,
  'warehouse' => $warehouse,
]);
```

and ajax success function

```
success:function(res){
  let item_categories = res.item_categories,
      warehouse = res.warehouse;
  // process options
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `<option>` have an id value from Categories table, is that suggest you?

First you have to define relationship between them (table Categories and Warehouse) on Model. (One- to many)

Then you have to create 2 function into your controller, the first function to get all Category data, and the last one is filter Warehouse table with id of Category.

Example:

*function get Categories table data*

> `public function getCategories(){`
> `$category = CategoryModel::getAll();`
> `return response()->json('data'=> $category);`
> `}`

*function filter Warehouse by id (of Categories table)/example*

> `public function filterWarehouse($id){`
> `// using Eloquent or QueryBuilder to find all Warehouse data by $id (Categories table)`
> `return response()->json($wareHouseDataById);`
> `}`

Then, in your view, you have to call an ajax to get all Categories Data (whatever your route name that you defined to call two function above ) and fill Categories data into your `<option>` tag. Ready to add `onclick` event filter each option.

```
<option value='+ data.data.id +' onclick="getWarehouseFilter(data.data.id)">'+ data.data.name+'</option>
```

And the last job is make new javascript function and call another ajax to get Warehouse data (second function). (in purpose onclick event)

Example ajax call filter warehouse data:

> `function getWarehouseFilter(id){`
> `let id = $(this).attr(id);`
> or
> `let id = $(this).target.value;`
> `$.ajax({`
>   `url: '/getFilterWarehouseData....',`
>   `method: 'post',`
>   `data: {id: id},`
>   `dataType: 'json',`
>   `success: function(data){`
>   `$('#htmlNeedToRenderData').html(rawHtml(your custom) + data )`
>   `// do not use append() in this case.`
>   `},`
>   `error: function(response){`
>   `// do whatever if got an error`
>   `}`
>   `})`
> `}`

I hope this will be helped u.